# How to train SVM model in sklearn python by input CSV file?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have used sklearn scikit python for prediction. While importing following package

**from sklearn import datasets**  and storing the result in **iris = datasets.load_iris()**  , it works fine to train model

```
iris = pandas.read_csv("E:\scikit\sampleTestingCSVInput.csv") 
iris_header = ["Sepal_Length","Sepal_Width","Petal_Length","Petal_Width"]
```

**Model Algorithm :**

```
model = SVC(gamma='scale')
model.fit(iris.data, iris.target_names[iris.target])
```

But while importing CSV file to train model , creating new array for target_names also , I am facing some error  like

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [150, 4]

My CSV file has 5 Columns in which 4 columns are input and 1 column is output. Need to fit model for that output column.

How to provide argument for fit model?

Could anyone share the code sample to import CSV file to fit SVM model in sklearn python?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to stack Overflow, please go through [How to ask Questios](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ask the question with a minimum verifiable example, What did you do, upload some code snippets that lead to the error.

Comment: how many columns are there in the csv file? can you share the output of `print(iris.columns())`

Comment: `iris.columns`
Index([u'Sepal_Length', u'Sepal_Width', u'Petal_Length', u'Petal_Width',
       u'Species'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: @KavinRaj If you are adding additional Information to you rquestion, the preffered method to do is by making edits to your question

Comment: @KavinRaj Also there are multiple Issues in your fit statement, you are supposed to fit them as numpy array, and the second variable is your target, Which you need to specify in your question as what you want it to be.

Comment: @anand_v.singh Is the second variable is required an array or single column name as string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question was not very clear to begin with and attempts to explain it were going in vain, I decided to download the dataset and do it for myself. So just to make sure we are working with the same dataset `iris.head()` will give you or something similar, a few names might be changed and a few values, but overall strucure will be the same.
[image: iris.head()]

Now the first four columns are features and the fifth one is target/output.

Now you will need your X and Y as numpy arrays, to do that use

```
X = iris[ ['sepal length:','sepal Width:','petal length','petal width']].values
Y = iris[['Target']].values
```

Now since Y is categorical Data, You will need to one hot encode it using sklearn's LabelEncoder and scale the input X to do that use

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = label_encoder.fit_transform(Y)
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

To keep with the norm of separate train and test data, split the dataset using

```
X_train , X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y)
```

Now just train it on your model using X_train and y_train

```
clf = SVC(C=1.0, kernel='rbf').fit(X_train,y_train)
```

After this you can use the test data to evaluate the model and tune the value of C as you wish.

**Edit** Just in case you don't know where the functions are here are the import statements

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
```